# TensorFlow Variable Shape assign

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to create a variable and then trying to assign it with the value of my convolution layer.

However it is refusing because it is saying shapes are not equal even though I have passed `validate_shape=False` while creating the variable.

The convolution shape is `[32,20,20,3]`. How do I pass this into the variable?

## the bottom code:

```
conv = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(conv, filters=3, kernel_size=3, strides=(2,2), padding='same',activation=tf.nn.relu) # TO ASSIGN LATER


g=tf.Variable(([32,20,20]),dtype=tf.float32,validate_shape=False)#THE VARIABLE


loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(conv))
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
saver = tf.train.Saver()



with tf.Session() as sess:

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for i in range(1000):
    
    _, xx,inp,output,target = sess.run([opt, loss,x,conv,y])#
    print(xx)
 
    
    print("subtraction result:",output[0]-target[0])
    
    g=g.assign(conv)
    print(g.eval())
```

I am getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [3] rhs shape= [32,20,20,3]
     [[Node: Assign_7 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, use_locking=false, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Variable_9, conv2d_transpose_98/Relu)]]
```

Can someone please help fix this?

Comment: its all indented correct in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

g = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.zeros((32,20,20,3)), expected_shape=(32,20,20,3), dtype=tf.float32)
```

If you print `g` you get the correct shape now:

```
<tf.Variable 'Variable_3:0' shape=(32, 20, 20, 3) dtype=float32_ref>
```

What you did was this:

```
g = tf.Variable(initial_value=(32,20,20), dtype=tf.float32, valid_shape=False)
```

By not stating `expected_shape` you defaulted to positional arguments, the first argument of `tf.Variable` is `initial_value` as per the documentation below:

```
__init__(
    initial_value=None,
    trainable=True,
    collections=None,
    validate_shape=True,
    caching_device=None,
    name=None,
    variable_def=None,
    dtype=None,
    expected_shape=None,
    import_scope=None,
    constraint=None
)
```

That shape of the `initial_value` you declared would have been a vector of length `[3]` which is exactly the shape that the assign operation is complaining about.

Moral of the story: it's generally less buggy to declare arguments by name if you can. :)